# Django: UNIQUE constraint failed: users_customuser.email

Tags: django

i keep getting this error when i try to register for the second time i have tried multiple possible solutions but i keep getting it anyway any help ?

```
IntegrityError at /registration/transporteur
```

this is my code:
here i try to have multi type users

**models.py**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length= 15, )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length= 15)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length= 15)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'),unique= True,)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length= 15)
    address = models.CharField(verbose_name = "Address", max_length= 50, null = True, blank= True)
    # profile_picture = models.ImageField(null = True)
    # longitude = models.CharField(verbose_name = "Longitude", max_length= 100, null = True, blank= True)
    # lagitude = models.CharField(verbose_name = "Lagitude", max_length= 100, null = True, blank= True)

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_transporteur = models.BooleanField(default= False)
    is_client = models.BooleanField(default= False) 
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default= False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default= False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default= False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["first_name", "last_name", "username",  "phone_number", "address"]
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    def has_perm(self, perm: str, obj: None):
        return self.is_admin
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True


class Trasporteur(CustomUser):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="trasporteur_account")
    matricule = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank=True, null=True)
    car_type = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices = CAR_tYPES)
    rating = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null = True)
    current_location = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank=True, null=True)
    is_on_travail = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bio = models.TextField()
    # last_transports = models.ManyToManyField('transport_services.TrasportService', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="trasporteur_transports")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Client(CustomUser):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="client_account")
    current_location = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank=True, null=True)
    # last_transports = models.ManyToManyField('transport_services.TrasportService', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="client_transports")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**managers.py**

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):

        if not username:
            raise ValueError(_('The username must be set'))
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        
        username = username
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username = username, email = email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
```

**serializers.py**
there is a separate registration and retrieve serializers for each class and the custom user one is just for test it is also the main one

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__'


class TransporteurSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.CharField(read_only=True,)
    class Meta:
        model = Trasporteur
        fields = '__all__'
    

class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.CharField(read_only=True,)
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = '__all__'
    

class TransporteurCustomRegistrationSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True,)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    address = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    matricule = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    car_type = serializers.ChoiceField(choices= CAR_tYPES)

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
            data = super(TransporteurCustomRegistrationSerializer, self).get_cleaned_data()
            extra_data = {
                'first_name' : self.validated_data.get('first_name', ''),
                'last_name' : self.validated_data.get('last_name', ''),
                'phone_number' : self.validated_data.get('phone_number', ''),
                'address' : self.validated_data.get('address', ''),
                'matricule' : self.validated_data.get('matricule', ''),
                'car_type' : self.validated_data.get('car_type', ''),
            }
            data.update(extra_data)
            return data

    def save(self, request):
        user = super(TransporteurCustomRegistrationSerializer, self).save(request)
        user.is_transporteur = True
        user.username = self.data.get('username')
        user.email = self.data.get('email')
        user.first_name = self.data.get('first_name')
        user.last_name = self.data.get('last_name')
        user.phone_number = self.data.get('phone_number')
        user.address = self.data.get('address')
        user.matricule = self.data.get('matricule')
        user.car_type = self.data.get('car_type')
        user.save()
        transporteur = Trasporteur(
            user=user,
            email=self.cleaned_data.get('email'), 
            first_name=self.cleaned_data.get('first_name'), 
            last_name=self.cleaned_data.get('last_name'), 
            phone_number = self.cleaned_data.get('phone_number'),
            address = self.cleaned_data.get('address'),
            matricule=self.cleaned_data.get('matricule'), 
            car_type=self.cleaned_data.get('car_type'),
            )
        transporteur.save()
        return user


class ClientCustomRegistrationSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True,) 
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    address = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    
    def get_cleaned_data(self):
            data = super(ClientCustomRegistrationSerializer, self).get_cleaned_data()
            extra_data = {
                'first_name' : self.validated_data.get('first_name', ''),
                'last_name' : self.validated_data.get('last_name', ''),
                'phone_number' : self.validated_data.get('phone_number', ''),
                'address' : self.validated_data.get('address', ''),
            }
            data.update(extra_data)
            return data

    def save(self, request):
        user = super(ClientCustomRegistrationSerializer, self).save(request)
        user.is_client = True
        user.email = self.data.get('email')
        user.first_name = self.data.get('first_name')
        user.last_name = self.data.get('last_name')
        user.phone_number = self.data.get('phone_number')
        user.address = self.data.get('address')
        user.save()
        client = Client(
            user=user,
            email=self.cleaned_data.get('email'), 
            first_name=self.cleaned_data.get('first_name'), 
            last_name=self.cleaned_data.get('last_name'), 
            phone_number = self.cleaned_data.get('phone_number'),
            address = self.cleaned_data.get('address'),
            )
        client.save()
        return user
```

**settings related to django rest auth**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_USERNAME = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = False
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'optional'
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = '/?verification=1'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = '/?verification=1'

SITE_ID = 1
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing the inheritance from custom user. You wouldn't inherit from the abstract class.

```
Trasporteur(CustomUser) => Trasporteur(models.Model):
```